# How can i create a view query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, powerbi, business-intelligence

How can i create a view using existing accounts receivables query which includes ageing & joins & temp tables in SQL, I have to use that filtered columns  view in power BI

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Have you attempted to do so and did you have a problem. If no try reading the manual.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

For a simple select view in SQL Server, you first write the query, then add `CREATE VIEW AS` in front of it. Be careful though, do not specify `SELECT *` in your query, instead, specify the columns you want by name. If you don't, your query is likely to fail if you change columns in the underlying table later.

A view can  have up to 1024 columns and the `CREATE VIEW` statement must be the first statement in the batch.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2
FROM
    MyTable
    INNER JOIN MyOtherTable ON MtTable.ID = MyOtherTable.MyTableID
```

To use the view, you can just write

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
```